# Access 2013 Design View Ruler not showing

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

This is a really weird one!

I cant see a ruler in my design view of my access any more.

I have not changed any settings that I am aware of.

This is what is looks like when I am in design view now.

[image]

Please let me know if you have encountered this and know a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the details section and click on Ruler to re-enable it.

You can also go to the Ribbon, under Form Design, Arrange tab, Size and Space button, click Ruler.